# Count Connected Strings in Matrix Java using recursion

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am supposed to count how many @ signs are connected to the original predetermined spot in a 2D array matrix. I am getting a stack overflow error and do not know why. Any suggestions are appreciated (Take a provided row and col location and count how many @ signs connect to the original location. @ signs are connected if they are connected up, down, left, and right of one another.)

Current Code:

```
   import static java.lang.System.*;

public class AtCounter
{
   private String[][] atMat;
   private int totalCount = 0;
   private boolean[][] visited; //used to see if location has been visited before.
   public AtCounter(int rows, int cols)
   {
       //size the matrix
       atMat = new String[rows][cols];
       //use nested loops to randomly load the matrix
       for(int r = 0; r < atMat.length; r++)
       {
           for(int c = 0; c < atMat[r].length; c++)
           {
               int num = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
               if(num == 0)
                   atMat[r][c] = "@";
               else
                   atMat[r][c] = "-";
           }
       }
       //you will need to use Math.random()

        visited = new boolean[atMat.length][atMat.length];
   }
   /**
    * Used to find out if location is in the 2D Matrix.
    */
   public boolean inBounds(int r, int c)
   {
        return ((r > -1 && r < atMat.length) && (c > -1 && c < atMat.length));
   }
   public int countAts(int r, int c)
   {
        //add in recursive code to count up the # of @s connected
        //start checking at spot [r,c]

        if(atMat[r][c].equals("-") || !inBounds(r,c))
            return 0;
        if(!visited[r][c])
        {
            if(atMat[r][c].equals("@"))
            {
                totalCount+=1;

                if(inBounds(r - 1, c))//up
                    countAts(r - 1, c);

                if(inBounds(r + 1, c))//down
                    countAts(r + 1, c);

                if(inBounds(r, c + 1))//right
                    countAts(r , c + 1);

                if(inBounds(r, c  - 1))//left
                    countAts(r, c - 1);
            }
        }
        return totalCount;        
     }


    /*
     *this method will return all values in the matrix
     *this method should return a view of the matrix
     *that looks like a matrix
     */
    public String toString()
    {
        String grid = "";
        for(String[] row : atMat)
        {
            for(String val : row)
            {
                grid += val + " ";
            }
            grid += "\n";
        }
        return grid;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Without looking at your code - most likely a case of infinite recursion.

Comment: Hey programmerperson, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The recursive method countsAts is blowing the stack. Please try use the debugging techniques to resolve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several errors in your code:

- You are created the `visited` arrays using `atMat.length` which will create an square array even if your original dimensions (*rows* and *cols*) aren't equal.
- In the `inBounds` method you the column argument `c` against the length of the rows, not the length of the columns
- In the `countAts` method:

  - The checking order of the invalid conditions needs to be reversed, you need to check first if it is valid position and later if the value in that cell is an @.
  - If the current cell hasn't been visited then the first thing is to marked as visited within the if block, to avoid falling in an endless recursion.

With all that said, a possible solution could be as follows:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class AtCounter
{
    private String[][] atMat;
    private int totalCount = 0;
    private boolean[][] visited; //used to see if location has been visited before.

    private int rows; // To store rows length
    private int cols; // To store cols length

    public AtCounter(int rows, int cols)
    {
        //size of the matrix
        this.rows = rows;
        this.cols = cols;
        atMat = new String[rows][cols];

        //use nested loops to randomly load the matrix
        for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
            for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
                int num = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
                if(num == 0)
                    atMat[r][c] = "@";
                else
                    atMat[r][c] = "-";
            }

        visited = new boolean[rows][cols];
    }

    /**
    * Used to find out if location is in the 2D Matrix.
    */
    public boolean inBounds(int r, int c)
    {
        return r > -1 && r < rows && c > -1 && c < cols;
    }

    public int countAts(int r, int c)
    {
        //add in recursive code to count up the # of @s connected
        //start checking at spot [r,c]

        if(!inBounds(r,c) || atMat[r][c].equals("-")) // The order here matters
            return 0;

        if(!visited[r][c])
        {
            visited[r][c] = true; // Marks the current cell as visited
            if(atMat[r][c].equals("@"))
            {
                totalCount+=1;

                if(inBounds(r - 1, c))//up
                    countAts(r - 1, c);

                if(inBounds(r + 1, c))//down
                    countAts(r + 1, c);

                if(inBounds(r, c + 1))//right
                    countAts(r , c + 1);

                if(inBounds(r, c  - 1))//left
                    countAts(r, c - 1);
            }
        }
        return totalCount;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help aegis!

Comment: didn't realize that was an option haha, thanks again

Comment: You're welcome, furthermore you should check [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) post in the meta for more info